# Catch uploaded file name in Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, file-upload, slug, fat-free-framework

My php script has to handle with non-slug filename uploads, when for example, a user tries to upload a file "Имя на русском.jpg". Some methods don't handle it correct, so i use:

```
$overwrite = true;
$slug = true;
\Web::instance()->receive(NULL,$overwrite,$slug);
```

So, I get the "imja-na-russkom.jpg" file on server. The problem is that I need to catch this filename for DB, for which I tried this:

```
$filename = \Web::instance()->Slug($_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

Which returns "imja-na-russkom-jpg" - not the name used in filesystem (not dot, but dash before extension).

So, my question is: Is there a way to catch the name, used in Web::receive() or, if not, is there a workaround to get it by means of F3? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, with ikkez' tip i figured that out:

```
$a = Web::instance()->receive(NULL,true,true);
$name = array_keys($a);
$name = pathinfo($name['0'], PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

Here we upload file on the server and save it's name into $name variable. You can skip the last line and use

```
$name = $name['0'];
```

if you want to save the full path to your uploaded file.

Comment: What happened if your file did not upload correctly ? $name  variable still returns the name and you will store the name of a file that does not exist on the server. I think you should check boolean value as well.

Answer (score 2):

the \Web::instance()->receive function returns an array of files that where uploaded. you'll see the slugged name in the array keys. check the example at http://fatfreeframework.com/web#receive